# Using library with different names within autoconf

Tags: autoconf, gentoo, pkg-config

I am trying to build an application with OpenSync 0.4 (0.3.9 indeed) dependency.

In the project's configure.ac the opensync library is written as `libopensync1`. However, this doesn't build on my Gentoo system. Changing `libopensync1` to `libopensync` does fix the issue for me.

I searched with Google and found that `libopensync1` is used in some distributions, while `libopensync` in others. So how to resolve this issue in `configure.ac`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the place at which this occurs inside your `configure.ac` is inside a `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` call.

Looking at the libopensync sources, it seems that `libopensync1` is the newer name, and `libopensync` is the old name. So, we'll use pkg-config macros to look for the newer name *unless* it doesn't exist.

Put this in your `configure.ac`:

```
# Check if libopensync1 is known to pkg-config, and if not, look for libopensync instead
PKG_CHECK_EXISTS([libopensync1], [OPENSYNC=libopensync1], [OPENSYNC=libopensync])
```

Then later in your `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` call, replace `libopensync1` with `$OPENSYNC`.

Answer (score 4):

The macro AC_SEARCH_LIBS does what you need.  (There is much heated debate about whether or not pkg-config should ever be used.  If you choose to rely on it, ptomato gives a reasonable approach.)  Simply add this to your configure.ac:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([osync_mapping_new],[opensync1 opensync],[],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR([can't find opensync])])
```

This will first look for a library named opensync1; if
it doesn't find that, it will look for opensync.

The primary drawback of using pkg-config is that most projects that
rely on it do not actually check if the data provided by the .pc
file is reliable, so configure may succeed but a subsequent build
will fail.  It is always possible for a user to set PKG_CONFIG=true
when running configure and completely eliminate all of the data
provided by any associated .pc files, setting LIBS, CFLAGS, etc by
hand the 'old-fashioned' way.

The primary drawback of not using pkg-config is that the user
has to set LIBS, CFLAGS, etc. the old-fashioned way.  In practice,
this is pretty trivial, and all pkg-config has done is move the
data from a single CONFIG_SITE file to separately maintained
.pc files for each package.

If you do use PKG_MODULE_CHECK, follow it up with a call to
AC_CHECK_LIB or AC_SEARCH_LIBS to validate the data in whatever
.pc file was located by PKG_CHECK_MODULES